# windows phone 8.1 silverlight calendar

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, controls

I've been struggling to add a calendar control to my windows phone 8.1 silverlight application but i found nothing, i used syncfusion calendar control once but it was a windows phone 8.1 application not silverlight one, please anyone can provide a useful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the Calendar control for WindowsPhone Silverlight from ComponentOne. You could download it from https://www.componentone.com/Downloads/Download/?downloadID=133 and refer to its documentation at : http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/WPCalendar/